# Creating a new Android Application/Activity in Eclipse creates a new Layout AND Fragment Layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

Whenever I create a new Android Project or Activity in Eclipse, it creates both a Layout and a Fragment Layout (two separate xml documents in the Resource folder). Now, I just updated my SDK, so i think this may have to do with it. Is there any advantage to this dual-Layout method? How can I revert back to just creating one new Layout document for new Applications/Activities?